# SQL Query to convert rows amount to column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have written the following query -

```
SELECT element_name,
element_start_date,
element_end_date,
period_name,
element_classfication,
Person_number
from per_elements
where element_name in ('Employer Contribution','HSA Employee Contribution')
```

gives the following output

```
Element_name                element_start_date          element_end_date            Period_name             element_classfication   Person_number   Amount                      
Employer Contribution       6/14/2020                   6/27/2020                   14 2020 Biweekly        Liability               100             38
HSA Employee Contribution   6/14/2020                   6/27/2020                   14 2020 Biweekly        Deduction               100             19
```

Can i change the above query such that I get the following output -

```
element_start_date    element_end_date   Period_name        Person_number       Employer contribution amount    Employee contribution amount                        
6/14/2020             6/27/2020         14 2020 Biweekly    100                 38                              19
```

Can i convert the seperate rows to columns such that amount can be reflected side by side.

Comment: Google `pivot query` for such task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT element_start_date,
       element_end_date,
       period_name,
       Person_number,
       max(case when element_name = 'Employer Contribution' then amount end) 
         as employer_contribution_amount,
       max(case when element_name = 'HSA Employee Contribution' then amount end) 
         as employee_contribution_amount
    from per_elements
   where element_name in ('Employer Contribution','HSA Employee Contribution')
group by element_start_date,
         element_end_date,
         period_name,
         Person_number;
```

Comment: This is giving me MAX of the whole amount values not per person

Comment: I dont agree. I have used `person_number` in `group by` so it must be per person

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from 
   (
   select Element_name,element_start_date,element_end_date,Period_name,Person_number,Amount
   from per_elements
   where element_name in ('Employer Contribution','HSA Employee Contribution')
   )
pivot (
  sum(amount)
  for Element_name in ('Employer Contribution','HSA Employee Contribution')
)
/
```